# Use a connection string for RabbitMQ configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

When configuring RabbitMQ in a Spring Boot API, usually go to `application.properties` file and add

```
# RabbitMQ
spring.rabbitmq.host=host
spring.rabbitmq.port=port
spring.rabbitmq.username=user
spring.rabbitmq.password=password
```

wondering if it's possible, without having to create a custom property, to have a connection string like

```
amqp://user:password@host:port/
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Well, think that you can use `spring.rabbitmq.addresses` to do it :

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=amqp://user:password@host:port
```

It is documented at [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.amqp.rabbitmq) :

> Alternatively, you could configure the same connection using the addresses attribute:
>
> *spring.rabbitmq.addresses=amqp://admin:secret@localhost*
>
> When specifying addresses that way, the host and port properties are
> ignored. If the address uses the amqps protocol, SSL support is
> enabled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

And with a vhost:

spring.rabbitmq.addresses=amqp://user:password@host:port/virtualhost